# Name of an intermediary class that represents the data in another class

Tags: oop, class, object, business-logic-layer, multi-tier

Is there a standard name for a class meant to represent another class, but keeping it distinct;

An example should help illustrate: say my business layer has access to an object of class such as .NET's System.Diagnostics.Process which contains a lot of information about the processes running on your system. Another project, such as a system resource project has no use for all that information so in the business layer, I implement a class ProcessInfo which contains only the attributes deemed to matter.

Is there a name for such intermediary, representative classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call it a wrapper class so something like: ProcessInfoWrapper